# What is the correct way to create a timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, date

Given a year, month, day, hour, minute and second, what is the correct way to create a Java UTC (GMT) timestamp?

Options I've considered, but remain to be convinced by:

### 1 - use deprecated Date constructors

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(year - 1900, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute, second);
long timestamp = date.getTime();
```

### 2 - use a calendar with TimeZone set to GMT

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long timestamp = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

One of my issues with this is that I'm finding it very hard to test without getting mixed up in more TimeZone issues.

Is there a definitive right way to do this with the standard APIs?

Update: would like to get an answer to this using standard JavaSE.  I know Joda-Time is wonderful, but it's not an option in this case.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 34 , 56 , 0, ZoneOffset.UTC )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Unlike the troublesome legacy date-time classes, the *java.time* classes use sane numbering:

- `2018` means the year 2018. (No crazy math with 1900.)
- 1-12 for months January-December. (Not silly 0-11.)
- 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per [ISO 8601 standard definition of week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). (No varying by locale.)

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

You a one-liner if you wish, if parsing a string.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-01-23T12:34:56Z" ) ;
```

While `Instant` is a basic building-block class for *java.time*, the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class is more flexible. The offset-from-UTC of UTC itself is [defined as a constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) for your convenience.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 34 , 56 , 0, ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Personally, I prefer using pieces.

In place of a mere integer for month, you may specify a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;  // Date-only, without time-of-day.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 , 56 ) ;  // Time-of-day, without date.
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , offset ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't (unless you can use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)), the correct way is to use **Calendar** and the calendar API **is** ugly, nothing anyone can do about it at the moment.

Comment: Haha I guess I should be happy then.  Thanks :(

Answer (score 1):

Standard Java APIs for dates are pretty inconvenient. Consider using [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
long timestamp = new LocalDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
    .getLocalMillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work pretty good

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
Date date = sdf.parse("2011-12-21 12:00:00+0000");
```

You would have to build the date string on your own but it's short and should work fine. And create the SimpleDateFormat to your liking, the important part is the Z that corresponds to 
"+0000".

Here is another alternative way on the same lines

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = sdf.parse("2011-12-21 12:00:00");
```

It's with an explicit time zone and the Z is removed.

Comment: This certainly looks neat and sensible and readable.  Might not be quite so sweet once all my variables are sloshing about, but will give it a go.